# Is there any way to check which of my posts on meta was upvoted?

Tags: discussion, meta, votes

When I hover the cursor over my username *on this site*, a small box comes up giving 'votes, votes cast...' for the last day, week and month. If I see a +1 in the first row , is there any way to check which post has attracted favourable attention? On the main site, I could just check my reputation; but here, it seems I would have to look at each of my posts, and try to remember what its score was last time.

Comment: Just look around your personal site....[here you go](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/8019/TimLymington?tab=reputation)

Comment: @Mitch I believe OP is talking about meta. The problem here is that you don't gain real rep from votes.

Comment: @Luke: Oh. Right. Yea, I don't think that exists for meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created [a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/englishmeta/query/87998/top-100-votes) that shows the votes you get between accepted answers, down-votes, and up-votes. The given link is for the question; in the case the vote is for the answer, the link will be for the question containing the answer.

[image: screenshot]

The data in the Data Explorer are updated more frequently, now. As I see from [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/englishmeta/query/13414/what-data-dump-is-sede-using), Data Explorer is using data updated to December, 2012.

Comment: Thanks for this: if you can tell me *how* to get it, I'll accept it gratefully.

Comment: Click on the link labeled as "query"; be sure to logged in on Data Explorer; click on "Run Query." When you are logged-in on Data Explorer, the user ID is automatically entered. The query lists the last 100 votes.